# JSON RPC Returns 'Invalid API parameter' upon request in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create my own jsonrpc client for a project, using python and requests. After an hour of searching online, Most errors are to do with people executing a get rather than a post or people getting a different error. According the the JSONRPC Spec (Found Here http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) It should work. Any help would be most grateful. Thanks Sam.

Requests & Code Below:

Post Request Body:

```
{"method": "GudMethod", "params": {"ur": "HELLO"}, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1}
```

Request Response:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "method": "GudMethod",
    "success": false,
    "error": "Invalid API parameter [jsonrpc] must be 2.0 [\"GudMethod\"]",
    "extra": [],
    "metrics": {
        "st": "2018-05-24 22:16:37",
        "sspt": 0.0006299018859863281
    }
},
"id": null
}
```

Codes:

```
import json
import requests

class Client():
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url = url
        self.id = 0

    def request(self,method,prms):
        rq = Request(self,method,prms)
        return rq

class Request():
    def __init__(self,client,method,prms):
        self.client = client
        self.method = method
        self.prms = prms
        self.rq = None

    def buildRequest(self):
        self.client.id = self.client.id + 1
        url = self.client.url + "?method={}".format(self.method)
        jb = {}
        jb["jsonrpc"] = "2.0"
        jb["method"] = self.method
        jb["params"] = self.prms
        jb["id"] = self.client.id
        body = json.dumps(jb)
        return url,body
    def execute(self):
        url , body = self.buildRequest()
        self.rq = requests.post(url,data=body)
        print(body)
        print(self.rq.text)
```

Also, dont ask me to use a ready made one. I was told that already, but due to where the project will be used, I can't install any librarys. Luckily requests will be installed, that would be painful otherwise

Comment: tried that a few days ago, just tried now. Does not work. The Spec asks for it in a string.

Comment: Is the order of parameters important in the request? In regular JSON I know this isn't true, but all the examples in the spec have jsonrpc as the first field. You can try using an OrderedDict to build the request, so that the request json has the correct order.

Comment: Nope. As a quick trial, I copied a request from the spec demo section and replaced strings inside it.                                                         
                                                                                                        
           body = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "#METHOD#", "params": #PRMS#, "id": #ID#}'.replace("#METHOD#",self.method,1).replace("#PRMS#",json.dumps(self.prms),1).replace("#ID#",str(self.client.id),1)

Answer (score 0):

Your client's request looks fine.

The server must be parsing your request incorrectly, assigning the value `GudMethod` to the name `jsonrpc`.

Not only is the server parsing your request incorrectly, but the response also is not valid according to the [JSON-RPC specification](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification):

1) There should be no `result` field:

> result
>     This member is REQUIRED on success.
>     **This member MUST NOT exist if there was an error invoking the method.**
>     The value of this member is determined by the method invoked on the Server.

2) There should be a top-level `error` field:

> error
>     **This member is REQUIRED on error.**
>     This member MUST NOT exist if there was no error triggered during invocation.
>     The value for this member MUST be an Object as defined in section 5.1.

3) The `error` field should be a JSON Object with the following fields:

> code
>     A Number that indicates the error type that occurred.
>     This MUST be an integer.
>   message
>     A String providing a short description of the error.
>     The message SHOULD be limited to a concise single sentence.
>   data
>     A Primitive or Structured value that contains additional information about the error.
>     This may be omitted.
>     The value of this member is defined by the Server (e.g. detailed error information, nested errors etc.).

As the server erroneously believes the `jsonrpc` field is not equal to `2.0`, the error `code` field should be -32600 and the message field `Invalid Request` indicating

> The JSON sent is not a valid Request object.